# Using pandas' groupby with shifting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, cumsum

I am looking to use `pd.rolling_mean` in a `groupby` operation. I want to have in each group a rolling mean of the *previous* elemnets within the same group. Here is an example:

```
id    val
0     1
0     2
0     3
1     4
1     5
2     6
```

Grouping by `id`, this should be transformed into:

```
id    val
0     nan
0     1
0     1.5
1     nan
1     4
2     nan
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want [**`pd.Series.expanding`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.expanding.html)

```
df.groupby('id').val.apply(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift())

0    NaN
1    1.0
2    1.5
3    NaN
4    4.0
5    NaN
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you need `groupby` with `shift` and `rolling`, window size can be set to scalar:

```
df['val']=df.groupby('id')['val'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean())
print (df)
   id  val
0   0  NaN
1   0  1.0
2   0  1.5
3   1  NaN
4   1  4.0
5   2  NaN
```

Thank you [`3novak`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141658/using-pandas-groupby-with-shifting/43141841#comment73361032_43141841) for comment - you can set window size by max length of group:

```
f = lambda x: x.shift().rolling(df['id'].value_counts().iloc[0], min_periods=1).mean()
df['val'] = df.groupby('id')['val'].apply(f)
print (df)
   id  val
0   0  NaN
1   0  1.0
2   0  1.5
3   1  NaN
4   1  4.0
5   2  NaN
```

Comment: I think OP's question may require a larger window size. 2 is sufficient for this data set, but it should be set to `df['id'].value_counts().iloc[0]`.